# How to change opacity in Javascript for object

Tags: javascript

Found code here for metaballs using vanilla javascript. Is there a way I can change the opacity of the metaballs? I think it should be a quick fix but im not too sure. I tried changing to CSS class bubbles but that didnt work so im assuming in needs to be in the Javascript. Anything helps, thanks.

Found code here for metaballs using vanilla javascript. Is there a way I can change the opacity of the metaballs? I think it should be a quick fix but im not too sure. I tried changing to CSS class bubbles but that didnt work so im assuming in needs to be in the Javascript. Anything helps, thanks.

```js
;(function() {

  "use strict";

  var lava0;
  var ge1doot = {
    screen: {
      elem:     null,
      callback: null,
      ctx:      null,
      width:    0,
      height:   0,
      left:     0,
      top:      0,
      init: function (id, callback, initRes) {
        this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
        this.callback = callback || null;
        if (this.elem.tagName == "CANVAS") this.ctx = this.elem.getContext("2d");
        window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
          this.resize();
        }.bind(this), false);
        this.elem.onselectstart = function () { return false; }
        this.elem.ondrag        = function () { return false; }
        initRes && this.resize();
        return this;
      },
      resize: function () {
        var o = this.elem;
        this.width  = o.offsetWidth;
        this.height = o.offsetHeight;
        for (this.left = 0, this.top = 0; o != null; o = o.offsetParent) {
          this.left += o.offsetLeft;
          this.top  += o.offsetTop;
        }
        if (this.ctx) {
          this.elem.width  = this.width;
          this.elem.height = this.height;
        }
        this.callback && this.callback();
      }
    }
  }

  // Point constructor
  var Point = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.magnitude = x * x + y * y;
    this.computed = 0;
    this.force = 0;
  };
  Point.prototype.add = function(p) {
    return new Point(this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y);
  };

  // Ball constructor
  var Ball = function(parent) {
    var min = .1;
    var max = 1.5;
    this.vel = new Point(
      (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * (0.2 + Math.random() * 0.25), (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * (0.2 + Math.random())
    );
    this.pos = new Point(
      parent.width * 0.2 + Math.random() * parent.width * 0.6,
      parent.height * 0.2 + Math.random() * parent.height * 0.6
    );
    this.size = (parent.wh / 15) + ( Math.random() * (max - min) + min ) * (parent.wh / 15);
    this.width = parent.width;
    this.height = parent.height;
  };

  // move balls
  Ball.prototype.move = function() {

    // bounce borders
    if (this.pos.x >= this.width - this.size) {
      if (this.vel.x > 0) this.vel.x = -this.vel.x;
      this.pos.x = this.width - this.size;
    } else if (this.pos.x <= this.size) {
      if (this.vel.x < 0) this.vel.x = -this.vel.x;
      this.pos.x = this.size;
    }

    if (this.pos.y >= this.height - this.size) {
      if (this.vel.y > 0) this.vel.y = -this.vel.y;
      this.pos.y = this.height - this.size;
    } else if (this.pos.y <= this.size) {
      if (this.vel.y < 0) this.vel.y = -this.vel.y;
      this.pos.y = this.size;
    }

    // velocity
    this.pos = this.pos.add(this.vel);

  };

  // lavalamp constructor
  var LavaLamp = function(width, height, numBalls, c0, c1) {
    this.step = 5;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.wh = Math.min(width, height);
    this.sx = Math.floor(this.width / this.step);
    this.sy = Math.floor(this.height / this.step);
    this.paint = false;
    this.metaFill = createRadialGradient(width, height, width, c0, c1);
    this.plx = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    this.ply = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1];
    this.mscases = [0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0];
    this.ix = [1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1];
    this.grid = [];
    this.balls = [];
    this.iter = 0;
    this.sign = 1;

    // init grid
    for (var i = 0; i < (this.sx + 2) * (this.sy + 2); i++) {
      this.grid[i] = new Point(
        (i % (this.sx + 2)) * this.step, (Math.floor(i / (this.sx + 2))) * this.step
      )
    }

    // create metaballs
    for (var k = 0; k < numBalls; k++) {
      this.balls[k] = new Ball(this);
    }
  };
  // compute cell force
  LavaLamp.prototype.computeForce = function(x, y, idx) {

    var force;
    var id = idx || x + y * (this.sx + 2);

    if (x === 0 || y === 0 || x === this.sx || y === this.sy) {
      force = 0.6 * this.sign;
    } else {
      force = 0;
      var cell = this.grid[id];
      var i = 0;
      var ball;
      while (ball = this.balls[i++]) {
        force += ball.size * ball.size / (-2 * cell.x * ball.pos.x - 2 * cell.y * ball.pos.y + ball.pos.magnitude + cell.magnitude);
      }
      force *= this.sign
    }
    this.grid[id].force = force;
    return force;
  };
  // compute cell
  LavaLamp.prototype.marchingSquares = function(next) {
    var x = next[0];
    var y = next[1];
    var pdir = next[2];
    var id = x + y * (this.sx + 2);
    if (this.grid[id].computed === this.iter) {
      return false;
    }
    var dir, mscase = 0;

    // neighbors force
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var idn = (x + this.ix[i + 12]) + (y + this.ix[i + 16]) * (this.sx + 2);
      var force = this.grid[idn].force;
      if ((force > 0 && this.sign < 0) || (force < 0 && this.sign > 0) || !force) {
        // compute force if not in buffer
        force = this.computeForce(
          x + this.ix[i + 12],
          y + this.ix[i + 16],
          idn
        );
      }
      if (Math.abs(force) > 1) mscase += Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    if (mscase === 15) {
      // inside
      return [x, y - 1, false];
    } else {
      // ambiguous cases
      if (mscase === 5) dir = (pdir === 2) ? 3 : 1;
      else if (mscase === 10) dir = (pdir === 3) ? 0 : 2;
      else {
        // lookup
        dir = this.mscases[mscase];
        this.grid[id].computed = this.iter;
      }
      // draw line
      var ix = this.step / (
          Math.abs(Math.abs(this.grid[(x + this.plx[4 * dir + 2]) + (y + this.ply[4 * dir + 2]) * (this.sx + 2)].force) - 1) /
          Math.abs(Math.abs(this.grid[(x + this.plx[4 * dir + 3]) + (y + this.ply[4 * dir + 3]) * (this.sx + 2)].force) - 1) + 1
        );
      ctx.lineTo(
        this.grid[(x + this.plx[4 * dir]) + (y + this.ply[4 * dir]) * (this.sx + 2)].x + this.ix[dir] * ix,
        this.grid[(x + this.plx[4 * dir + 1]) + (y + this.ply[4 * dir + 1]) * (this.sx + 2)].y + this.ix[dir + 4] * ix
      );
      this.paint = true;
      // next
      return [
        x + this.ix[dir + 4],
        y + this.ix[dir + 8],
        dir
      ];
    }
  };

  LavaLamp.prototype.renderMetaballs = function() {
    var i = 0, ball;
    while (ball = this.balls[i++]) ball.move();
    // reset grid
    this.iter++;
    this.sign = -this.sign;
    this.paint = false;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.metaFill;
    ctx.beginPath();
    // compute metaballs
    i = 0;
    //ctx.shadowBlur = 50;
    //ctx.shadowColor = "green";
    while (ball = this.balls[i++]) {
      // first cell
      var next = [
        Math.round(ball.pos.x / this.step),
        Math.round(ball.pos.y / this.step), false
      ];
      // marching squares
      do {
        next = this.marchingSquares(next);
      } while (next);
      // fill and close path
      if (this.paint) {
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.beginPath();
        this.paint = false;
      }
    }
  };

  // gradients
  var createRadialGradient = function(w, h, r, c0, c1) {
    var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(
      w / 1, h / 1, 0,
      w / 1, h / 1, r
    );
    gradient.addColorStop(0, c0);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, c1);
  };

  // main loop
  var run = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(run);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, screen.width, screen.height);
    lava0.renderMetaballs();
  };
  // canvas
  var screen = ge1doot.screen.init("bubble", null, true),
      ctx = screen.ctx;
  screen.resize();
  // create LavaLamps
  lava0 = new LavaLamp(screen.width, screen.height, 6, "#FF9298", "#E4008E");

  run();

})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <canvas id="bubble"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by changing the context alpha channel with RGBA (see at the very bottom `ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)' // NEW!` where 0.5 is the level of opacity - see ) :

```js
;
(function() {
  'use strict'

  var lava0
  var ge1doot = {
    screen: {
      elem: null,
      callback: null,
      ctx: null,
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      init: function(id, callback, initRes) {
        this.elem = document.getElementById(id)
        this.callback = callback || null
        if (this.elem.tagName == 'CANVAS') this.ctx = this.elem.getContext('2d')
        window.addEventListener(
          'resize',
          function() {
            this.resize()
          }.bind(this),
          false
        )
        this.elem.onselectstart = function() {
          return false
        }
        this.elem.ondrag = function() {
          return false
        }
        initRes && this.resize()
        return this
      },
      resize: function() {
        var o = this.elem
        this.width = o.offsetWidth
        this.height = o.offsetHeight
        for (this.left = 0, this.top = 0; o != null; o = o.offsetParent) {
          this.left += o.offsetLeft
          this.top += o.offsetTop
        }
        if (this.ctx) {
          this.elem.width = this.width
          this.elem.height = this.height
        }
        this.callback && this.callback()
      },
    },
  }

  // Point constructor
  var Point = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.magnitude = x * x + y * y
    this.computed = 0
    this.force = 0
  }
  Point.prototype.add = function(p) {
    return new Point(this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y)
  }

  // Ball constructor
  var Ball = function(parent) {
    var min = 0.1
    var max = 1.5
    this.vel = new Point(
      (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * (0.2 + Math.random() * 0.25),
      (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * (0.2 + Math.random())
    )
    this.pos = new Point(
      parent.width * 0.2 + Math.random() * parent.width * 0.6,
      parent.height * 0.2 + Math.random() * parent.height * 0.6
    )
    this.size = parent.wh / 15 + (Math.random() * (max - min) + min) * (parent.wh / 15)
    this.width = parent.width
    this.height = parent.height
  }

  // move balls
  Ball.prototype.move = function() {
    // bounce borders
    if (this.pos.x >= this.width - this.size) {
      if (this.vel.x > 0) this.vel.x = -this.vel.x
      this.pos.x = this.width - this.size
    } else if (this.pos.x <= this.size) {
      if (this.vel.x < 0) this.vel.x = -this.vel.x
      this.pos.x = this.size
    }

    if (this.pos.y >= this.height - this.size) {
      if (this.vel.y > 0) this.vel.y = -this.vel.y
      this.pos.y = this.height - this.size
    } else if (this.pos.y <= this.size) {
      if (this.vel.y < 0) this.vel.y = -this.vel.y
      this.pos.y = this.size
    }

    // velocity
    this.pos = this.pos.add(this.vel)
  }

  // lavalamp constructor
  var LavaLamp = function(width, height, numBalls, c0, c1) {
    this.step = 5
    this.width = width
    this.height = height
    this.wh = Math.min(width, height)
    this.sx = Math.floor(this.width / this.step)
    this.sy = Math.floor(this.height / this.step)
    this.paint = false
    this.metaFill = createRadialGradient(width, height, width, c0, c1)
    this.plx = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    this.ply = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
    this.mscases = [0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0]
    this.ix = [1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
    this.grid = []
    this.balls = []
    this.iter = 0
    this.sign = 1

    // init grid
    for (var i = 0; i < (this.sx + 2) * (this.sy + 2); i++) {
      this.grid[i] = new Point((i % (this.sx + 2)) * this.step, Math.floor(i / (this.sx + 2)) * this.step)
    }

    // create metaballs
    for (var k = 0; k < numBalls; k++) {
      this.balls[k] = new Ball(this)
    }
  }
  // compute cell force
  LavaLamp.prototype.computeForce = function(x, y, idx) {
    var force
    var id = idx || x + y * (this.sx + 2)

    if (x === 0 || y === 0 || x === this.sx || y === this.sy) {
      force = 0.6 * this.sign
    } else {
      force = 0
      var cell = this.grid[id]
      var i = 0
      var ball
      while ((ball = this.balls[i++])) {
        force +=
          (ball.size * ball.size) /
          (-2 * cell.x * ball.pos.x - 2 * cell.y * ball.pos.y + ball.pos.magnitude + cell.magnitude)
      }
      force *= this.sign
    }
    this.grid[id].force = force
    return force
  }
  // compute cell
  LavaLamp.prototype.marchingSquares = function(next) {
    var x = next[0]
    var y = next[1]
    var pdir = next[2]
    var id = x + y * (this.sx + 2)
    if (this.grid[id].computed === this.iter) {
      return false
    }
    var dir,
      mscase = 0

    // neighbors force
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var idn = x + this.ix[i + 12] + (y + this.ix[i + 16]) * (this.sx + 2)
      var force = this.grid[idn].force
      if ((force > 0 && this.sign < 0) || (force < 0 && this.sign > 0) || !force) {
        // compute force if not in buffer
        force = this.computeForce(x + this.ix[i + 12], y + this.ix[i + 16], idn)
      }
      if (Math.abs(force) > 1) mscase += Math.pow(2, i)
    }
    if (mscase === 15) {
      // inside
      return [x, y - 1, false]
    } else {
      // ambiguous cases
      if (mscase === 5) dir = pdir === 2 ? 3 : 1
      else if (mscase === 10) dir = pdir === 3 ? 0 : 2
      else {
        // lookup
        dir = this.mscases[mscase]
        this.grid[id].computed = this.iter
      }
      // draw line
      var ix =
        this.step /
        (Math.abs(
            Math.abs(this.grid[x + this.plx[4 * dir + 2] + (y + this.ply[4 * dir + 2]) * (this.sx + 2)].force) - 1
          ) /
          Math.abs(
            Math.abs(this.grid[x + this.plx[4 * dir + 3] + (y + this.ply[4 * dir + 3]) * (this.sx + 2)].force) - 1
          ) +
          1)
      ctx.lineTo(
        this.grid[x + this.plx[4 * dir] + (y + this.ply[4 * dir]) * (this.sx + 2)].x + this.ix[dir] * ix,
        this.grid[x + this.plx[4 * dir + 1] + (y + this.ply[4 * dir + 1]) * (this.sx + 2)].y + this.ix[dir + 4] * ix
      )
      this.paint = true
      // next
      return [x + this.ix[dir + 4], y + this.ix[dir + 8], dir]
    }
  }

  LavaLamp.prototype.renderMetaballs = function() {
    var i = 0,
      ball
    while ((ball = this.balls[i++])) ball.move()
    // reset grid
    this.iter++
      this.sign = -this.sign
    this.paint = false
    ctx.fillStyle = this.metaFill
    ctx.beginPath()
    // compute metaballs
    i = 0
    //ctx.shadowBlur = 50;
    //ctx.shadowColor = "green";
    while ((ball = this.balls[i++])) {
      // first cell
      var next = [Math.round(ball.pos.x / this.step), Math.round(ball.pos.y / this.step), false]
      // marching squares
      do {
        next = this.marchingSquares(next)
      } while (next)
      // fill and close path
      if (this.paint) {
        ctx.fill()
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.beginPath()
        this.paint = false
      }
    }
  }

  // gradients
  var createRadialGradient = function(w, h, r, c0, c1) {
    var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(w / 1, h / 1, 0, w / 1, h / 1, r)
    gradient.addColorStop(0, c0)
    gradient.addColorStop(1, c1)
  }

  // main loop
  var run = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(run)
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, screen.width, screen.height)
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)' // NEW!
    lava0.renderMetaballs()
  }
  // canvas
  var screen = ge1doot.screen.init('bubble', null, true),
    ctx = screen.ctx
  screen.resize()
  // create LavaLamps
  lava0 = new LavaLamp(screen.width, screen.height, 6, '#FF9298', '#E4008E')

  run()
})()
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <canvas id="bubble"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Lava constructor takes two colors, these can be modified to fit your color needs. By using `rgba()` versions of your colors, you can set the alpha (ie the opacity) or your bubbles/meatballs. However, before you do that, you need to return the `gradient` created in  `createRadialGradient` so that the colors can be used:

```
var createRadialGradient = function(w, h, r, c0, c1) {
  // ... code ...
  return gradient; // add this line
};
```

Now you can modify how you call your constructor:

```
// rgba versions of your colors -----------------------\/
lava0 = new LavaLamp(screen.width, screen.height, 6, "rgba(255, 146, 152, 0.5)", "rgba(228, 0, 142, 0.5)");
```

```js
;(function() {

  "use strict";

  var lava0;
  var ge1doot = {
    screen: {
      elem:     null,
      callback: null,
      ctx:      null,
      width:    0,
      height:   0,
      left:     0,
      top:      0,
      init: function (id, callback, initRes) {
        this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
        this.callback = callback || null;
        if (this.elem.tagName == "CANVAS") this.ctx = this.elem.getContext("2d");
        window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
          this.resize();
        }.bind(this), false);
        this.elem.onselectstart = function () { return false; }
        this.elem.ondrag        = function () { return false; }
        initRes && this.resize();
        return this;
      },
      resize: function () {
        var o = this.elem;
        this.width  = o.offsetWidth;
        this.height = o.offsetHeight;
        for (this.left = 0, this.top = 0; o != null; o = o.offsetParent) {
          this.left += o.offsetLeft;
          this.top  += o.offsetTop;
        }
        if (this.ctx) {
          this.elem.width  = this.width;
          this.elem.height = this.height;
        }
        this.callback && this.callback();
      }
    }
  }

  // Point constructor
  var Point = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.magnitude = x * x + y * y;
    this.computed = 0;
    this.force = 0;
  };
  Point.prototype.add = function(p) {
    return new Point(this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y);
  };

  // Ball constructor
  var Ball = function(parent) {
    var min = .1;
    var max = 1.5;
    this.vel = new Point(
      (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * (0.2 + Math.random() * 0.25), (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * (0.2 + Math.random())
    );
    this.pos = new Point(
      parent.width * 0.2 + Math.random() * parent.width * 0.6,
      parent.height * 0.2 + Math.random() * parent.height * 0.6
    );
    this.size = (parent.wh / 15) + ( Math.random() * (max - min) + min ) * (parent.wh / 15);
    this.width = parent.width;
    this.height = parent.height;
  };

  // move balls
  Ball.prototype.move = function() {

    // bounce borders
    if (this.pos.x >= this.width - this.size) {
      if (this.vel.x > 0) this.vel.x = -this.vel.x;
      this.pos.x = this.width - this.size;
    } else if (this.pos.x <= this.size) {
      if (this.vel.x < 0) this.vel.x = -this.vel.x;
      this.pos.x = this.size;
    }

    if (this.pos.y >= this.height - this.size) {
      if (this.vel.y > 0) this.vel.y = -this.vel.y;
      this.pos.y = this.height - this.size;
    } else if (this.pos.y <= this.size) {
      if (this.vel.y < 0) this.vel.y = -this.vel.y;
      this.pos.y = this.size;
    }

    // velocity
    this.pos = this.pos.add(this.vel);

  };

  // lavalamp constructor
  var LavaLamp = function(width, height, numBalls, c0, c1) {
    this.step = 5;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.wh = Math.min(width, height);
    this.sx = Math.floor(this.width / this.step);
    this.sy = Math.floor(this.height / this.step);
    this.paint = false;
    this.metaFill = createRadialGradient(width, height, width, c0, c1);
    this.plx = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    this.ply = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1];
    this.mscases = [0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0];
    this.ix = [1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1];
    this.grid = [];
    this.balls = [];
    this.iter = 0;
    this.sign = 1;

    // init grid
    for (var i = 0; i < (this.sx + 2) * (this.sy + 2); i++) {
      this.grid[i] = new Point(
        (i % (this.sx + 2)) * this.step, (Math.floor(i / (this.sx + 2))) * this.step
      )
    }

    // create metaballs
    for (var k = 0; k < numBalls; k++) {
      this.balls[k] = new Ball(this);
    }
  };
  // compute cell force
  LavaLamp.prototype.computeForce = function(x, y, idx) {

    var force;
    var id = idx || x + y * (this.sx + 2);

    if (x === 0 || y === 0 || x === this.sx || y === this.sy) {
      force = 0.6 * this.sign;
    } else {
      force = 0;
      var cell = this.grid[id];
      var i = 0;
      var ball;
      while (ball = this.balls[i++]) {
        force += ball.size * ball.size / (-2 * cell.x * ball.pos.x - 2 * cell.y * ball.pos.y + ball.pos.magnitude + cell.magnitude);
      }
      force *= this.sign
    }
    this.grid[id].force = force;
    return force;
  };
  // compute cell
  LavaLamp.prototype.marchingSquares = function(next) {
    var x = next[0];
    var y = next[1];
    var pdir = next[2];
    var id = x + y * (this.sx + 2);
    if (this.grid[id].computed === this.iter) {
      return false;
    }
    var dir, mscase = 0;

    // neighbors force
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var idn = (x + this.ix[i + 12]) + (y + this.ix[i + 16]) * (this.sx + 2);
      var force = this.grid[idn].force;
      if ((force > 0 && this.sign < 0) || (force < 0 && this.sign > 0) || !force) {
        // compute force if not in buffer
        force = this.computeForce(
          x + this.ix[i + 12],
          y + this.ix[i + 16],
          idn
        );
      }
      if (Math.abs(force) > 1) mscase += Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    if (mscase === 15) {
      // inside
      return [x, y - 1, false];
    } else {
      // ambiguous cases
      if (mscase === 5) dir = (pdir === 2) ? 3 : 1;
      else if (mscase === 10) dir = (pdir === 3) ? 0 : 2;
      else {
        // lookup
        dir = this.mscases[mscase];
        this.grid[id].computed = this.iter;
      }
      // draw line
      var ix = this.step / (
          Math.abs(Math.abs(this.grid[(x + this.plx[4 * dir + 2]) + (y + this.ply[4 * dir + 2]) * (this.sx + 2)].force) - 1) /
          Math.abs(Math.abs(this.grid[(x + this.plx[4 * dir + 3]) + (y + this.ply[4 * dir + 3]) * (this.sx + 2)].force) - 1) + 1
        );
      ctx.lineTo(
        this.grid[(x + this.plx[4 * dir]) + (y + this.ply[4 * dir]) * (this.sx + 2)].x + this.ix[dir] * ix,
        this.grid[(x + this.plx[4 * dir + 1]) + (y + this.ply[4 * dir + 1]) * (this.sx + 2)].y + this.ix[dir + 4] * ix
      );
      this.paint = true;
      // next
      return [
        x + this.ix[dir + 4],
        y + this.ix[dir + 8],
        dir
      ];
    }
  };

  LavaLamp.prototype.renderMetaballs = function() {
    var i = 0, ball;
    while (ball = this.balls[i++]) ball.move();
    // reset grid
    this.iter++;
    this.sign = -this.sign;
    this.paint = false;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.metaFill;
    ctx.beginPath();
    // compute metaballs
    i = 0;
    //ctx.shadowBlur = 50;
    //ctx.shadowColor = "green";
    while (ball = this.balls[i++]) {
      // first cell
      var next = [
        Math.round(ball.pos.x / this.step),
        Math.round(ball.pos.y / this.step), false
      ];
      // marching squares
      do {
        next = this.marchingSquares(next);
      } while (next);
      // fill and close path
      if (this.paint) {
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.beginPath();
        this.paint = false;
      }
    }
  };

  // gradients
  var createRadialGradient = function(w, h, r, c0, c1) {
    var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(
      w / 1, h / 1, 0,
      w / 1, h / 1, r
    );
    gradient.addColorStop(0, c0);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, c1);
    return gradient;
  };

  // main loop
  var run = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(run);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, screen.width, screen.height);
    lava0.renderMetaballs();
  };
  // canvas
  var screen = ge1doot.screen.init("bubble", null, true),
      ctx = screen.ctx;
  screen.resize();
  // create LavaLamps
  lava0 = new LavaLamp(screen.width, screen.height, 6, "rgba(255, 146, 152, 0.5)", "rgba(228, 0, 142, 0.5)");

  run();

})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <canvas id="bubble"></canvas>
</div>
```